# array returning true and only loops through the first item. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am working on a 4x4 sudoku program. I am trying to loop through the column of 2d array and returning false if an elements is not present otherwise return true. I have checked using console.log and my function is only looping through the first item and returning true.
Here is my code:

```js
function linearSearch(array, item) {
  var n = array.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (array[i] == item) {

      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

function checkColumn(puzzle, j) {
  //first make an array out of the values stored in column j
  let check = [];

  //call linearSearch on the array of column 
  //values for all values of k from 1 to 4
  for (var i = 0; i < puzzle.length; i++) {

    check.push(puzzle[i][j]);
  }
  console.log(check);

  for (var i = 0; i < check.length; i++) {
    if (linearSearch(check, check[i])) {
      console.log(i, check[i])
      return true;
    }

  }
  return false;
}

var puzzle1 = [
  [1, 2, 3, 4],
  [2, 3, 4, 1],
  [2, 3, 4, 1],
  [4, 1, 2, 3]
];
console.log(checkColumn(puzzle1, 2));

var puzzle = [
  [1, 2, 3, 4],
  [2, 3, 4, 1],
  [3, 4, 1, 2],
  [4, 1, 2, 3]
];
console.log(checkColumn(puzzle, 1));
```

any help would be appreciated thanks

Comment: What's the point of `linearCheck()`? It just confirms that an item from the array is in the array which is **always** true

Comment: I am hoping to loop though the array to figure out if all items in check array are in the array i.e. 1,2,3,4. if any item is missing then it should return false. but it stops at the first element

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand. Given you're passing `check` and `check[i]` into `linearCheck()`, it will **always** be `true` and you will exit out of `for (var i = 0; i < check.length; i++)` at the first iteration. It's really not clear what you want this code to do. _"returning false if an elements is not present"_... **what** element, exactly?

Comment: every 1st or 2nd or 3rd or 4th element of each array within the 2d array should be unique. For instance, checkColumn([1,2,3],[1,2,3],0). this checks whether the first element "1" is unique which it is not here because they are both 1 then it returns false

Comment: Nevermind. I figured it out. thanks though

Answer (score 0):

In `checkColumn` in the second loop, you put `return true` that breaks the loop because your `linearSearch` return true allways:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < check.length; i++) {
    if (linearSearch(check, check[i])) {
      console.log(i, check[i])
      return true;
    }

  }
```

Comment: I understand. is there a way where it loops though the whole array and then return a true or false without breaking out of the loop on the first instance